# $e^{-x}-x=0$ solution procedure

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

I realized that this exponential equation has to be solved using Lambert $w$ function, I also know that the result is $x= w(1)$, but I don't know how to get there. Would you mind helping me with this?

$$e^{-x}-x=0 $$

Comment: I took this way
e ^{−x} −x=0
1/e^{x}=x
e^{x}=1/x
x=ln{1/x}
x=ln1 - lnx
x=0-lnx
x+lnx=0

Answer (score 3):

$$ e^{-x}=x$$
$$\frac{1}{e^x}=x$$
$$xe^x=1$$, which by definition x=W(1).

Definition:
$$xe^x=C \rightarrow x=W(c)$$
[explanation and wiki](https://m.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.html)

:)

Answer (score 3):

Note that this is a transcendental equation which would fit in nicely into the form from wherein you can use the Lambert $W$ function.$$\begin{align}e^{-x}=x
\\ 1=xe^x \end{align} \\ x= W(1)$$
Also notice that $W(1)$ has a special value namely the Omega constant, $\Omega\approx0.56714329\ldots$